# Query a document and its nested array

Tags: mongodb, groovy

Using MongoDB and **Groovy** language

Having documents in a collection like the following

```
{
 id: 1,
 name: John,
 kids: [
  {
   name: Helen, 
   age: 13
  }, 
  {
   name: George, 
   age: 8}
 ]
}
```

How i can make a query like

```
db.collection.find(name: John AND kids name: Helen)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

`mongoCommand`

```
db.collectionName.find({
    $and: [
        {"name" : "John"},
        {"kids.name": "Helen"}
    ]
})
```

`groovy`

```
db.collection.find(new BasicDBObject(['name' : "John", 'kids.name' :"Helen"])).toArray().each {
    println it
}
```

if you have any question feel fre to ask

Comment: This is not Groovy language, the question is about groovy language